# How to create an Image object from a CanvasPixelArray

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I have two `<canvas>` elements in a document.

I want to draw a shape on canvas1, use the `ctx1.getImageData()` method to copy parts of that shape and animate these parts on canvas2.

I read that using `ctx2.putImageData()` is slower than using `ctx2.drawImage()`.

How can i create an `Image` object from a `CanvasPixelArray` (which is returned from the `ctx1.getImageData()` call) in JavaScript?

(Note: I don't want to copy the whole canvas1 but only parts of it. Also, I don't care about old browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want, unless I'm missing something:

`ctx2.drawImage(canvas1, source_x, source_y, source_width, source_height, dest_x, dest_y, dest_width, dest_height);`

The `drawImage()` function works with both `image` and `canvas` elements, so there is no need to create a new `image` object or a temporary `canvas` unless you need to manipulate the pixels.

Comment: i did not know this was possible. it actually works faster than using an image object (at least for my implementation). thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it. I have to create a temporary canvas element to and then use the `canvas.toDataURL()` method. I'd love to find a solution that does not use the temporary canvas, though.

```js
// ctx1 and ctx2 are the 2d context objects for canvas1 and canvas2

var image_data = ctx1.getImageData( 23, 43, 20, 20 );
var image = getImageObjectByImageData( image_data );

ctx2.drawImage( image, 20, 30 );

function getImageObjectByImageData( $image_data )
{
    var temp_canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        temp_canvas.height = $image_data.width;
        temp_canvas.width = $image_data.height;

    var temp_context = temp_canvas.getContext( '2d' );
        temp_context.putImageData( $image_data, 0, 0 );

    var img = new Image();
        img.width = $image_data.width;
        img.height = $image_data.height;
        img.src = temp_canvas.toDataURL();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, then you really should measure the difference between this and direct `putImageData`.